# Software Engineering: Conditionals evaluate "good" or "bad" order

Tags: if-statement

I remember reading in a software engineering book once that there is a typical rule to follow when writing `if else` conditional statements as to the order of evaluation. Should the **valid** case be evaluated first then followed by the **invalid**/**erroneous** case or vice versa? Is there a proper order for which cases should be evaluated first?

Example:

```
if (good) {
    // Exec some block of code for good case.
} else {
    // Bad case.
}
```

or

```
if (errorCase1) {
    // errorCase1 block.
} else if (errorCase2) {
    // errorCase2 block.
} else {
    // good case.
}
```

Comment: I believe this should be moved to [Programmers network](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No fixed rule as such I heard about the usage but I follow like this

```
if(usual)
{
(more often)
}
else (unusual)
{
(rarely occurring)
}
```

But if both have same function with different properties then better go for unusual first then usual so that you can save one instruction.

```
if(x == 0)  // 1
  {x = 1;}  // 2
else
  {x = 2;}  // 3
```